# Ionic 2.3.2 [CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj(61,5): error MSB4019]

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

When I run ionic build windows i get the below error

```
Building project: D:\app-Name\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj

    Configuration : debug
    Platform      : x64

D:\app-Name\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj(61,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio..Default.prop" was not found. 
Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1
```

My system info [ionic info]

```
Cordova CLI: 7.0.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

I have installed Visual Studio community edition 2017 along with specific 2015 and 2017 build tools including the SDK.

Added the min target preferences in config.xml. Even after everything i'm unable to build it.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Cordova looks for MSBuild tools version 14 of Visual Studio 2015.

These release notes suggest setting the environment variable `MSBUILDDIR` to the correct MSBuild directory [installed on your system](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2018/02/27/cordova-windows-6.0.0.html):

1. Install MSBuild tools 2015: https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=48159
2. Set environment variable `MSBUILDDIR` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin`